# How to reduce space between 2 message cell in MessageKit Library Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, chat, swift5, messagekit

I'm using MessageKit Chat Library. I removed the Avatar View from message cell. But the space between 2 message cells is too much. I want to reduce space between 2 message cell. how can I do that ?

---

**Edit:**

[image: I marked the spaces]

Comment: share screenshot

Comment: I shared the ss

Comment: have u checked cell spacing on collectionview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with cell spacing on cell in CollectionView

```
    if let layout = messagesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.textMessageSizeCalculator.outgoingAvatarSize = .zero
        layout.textMessageSizeCalculator.incomingAvatarSize = .zero
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    }
```

Comment: Where do you call this function? What if we need to have custom section insets for each cell? I tried to override messagePadding function but it doesn't seem to work! @redwheelbarrow